# How to delete the posts of user while deleting user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

```
router.delete('/delete',authenticate,async(req, res)=>{
const user = User.findById(req.rootUser._id)
{
    try{
        await Post.deleteMany({postedBy:rootUser})
        await User.findByIdAndDelete(req.rootUser._id)
        res.status(200).json(err);
    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
}
})
```

rootUser is the user, which we can access from authentication.

if I use id method like router.delete(':/id.............
then how to access post, because post id is different from user id.

POST SCHEMA:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema.Types
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    heading:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    confess:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    likes:[{type:ObjectId,ref:"USER"}],
   postedBy:{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "USER"
    }
});

const Post = module.exports = mongoose.model('POST', postSchema);
module.exports = Post;
```

Comment: Noite: This should really be a transaction, so if one fails there's a rollback and only commit on success of both queries. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html - the code right now could have one promise failing and the other succeeding.

Answer (score 1):

Since the postedBy field is of type ObjectId you have to pass in the _id of the user when you are searching for the posts to delete. Therfore you would have to do this:

```
await Post.deleteMany({postedBy: req.rootUser._id})
```

instead of just looking for `rootUser`, since, first off all, rootUser would be undefined (it should be `req.rootUser`) and we need the _id of the rootUser => `req.rootUser._id`

Comment: Then please upvote and mark the answer as correct 